# AHK – How to group different commands to a hotkey?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

In Photoshop I have 3 actions for my hotkey "g":

1. If I hold "space + g", zoom in and enable tool (zoom);
2. If tap "g", enable tool (smudge);

AND...

1. If I tap "g" 2 times, open menu (Ctrl+Alt+F12). If tap 4 times, open another menu (Shift+Alt+F1).

NOTE: Need to be "~g" to work.

**MY QUESTION:**

How to group code 1 and 2 together with the third?

This way the third code don't works:

```
; CODES 1 AND 2 — WORKS:

g::
if !GetKeyState("Space","U")
{
    Send, g ; CODE 2
    return
} else {
    Send, ^{Numpad0} ; CODE 1
    Sleep 10
    Send, z
    return
}


; CODES 3 — WORKS:

~g::
    if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~g" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
    {
        KeyWait, g
        return
    }
    Send, % ["^!{F12}","+!{F1}"][(count >= 2 || !count) ? count := 1 : ++count]
return

; --------------------------------------------------
; Trying to put together...
; CODES 1 AND 2 + CODE 3 — (THIRD DON'T WORKS):

g::
    if !GetKeyState("Space","U")
    {
        Send, g
        return
    } else {
        Send, ^{Numpad0}
        Sleep 10
        Send, z
        return
    }
    if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~g" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
    {
        KeyWait, g
        return
    }
    Send, % ["^!{F12}","+!{F1}"][(count >= 2 || !count) ? count := 1 : ++count]
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if the syntax of code below is correct because I'm newbie on AHK, but at least it works.

That works on Photoshop CC2015:

```
~g::
{
    Sleep, 150
    GetKeyState, state, g, U
    IfEqual, state, U
    {
        if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~g" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
        {
            KeyWait, g
            return
        }
        Send, % ["^!{F12}","+!{F1}"][(count >= 2 || !count) ? count := 1 : ++count]
        return
    }
    if !GetKeyState("Space","U")
    {
        Send, g
        return
    }
    else
    {
        Send, ^{Numpad0}
        Sleep 10
        Send, z
        return
    }
}
```